# How to start node server directly through browser?

Tags: node.js

Am looking forward to create a script that can start my node server directly through the browser without using "NPM start". My goal is, that I put localhost address in browser and it starts node server too automatically. Any idea how can I do it? Or, is it even possible to run node through browser without NPM commands.

Comment: This is not a client server communication strategy. You can do that server is a personal computer runs and host apps, client is your millions of browser from web phone across the world. You can't do that.

Comment: there a new feature called `WebContainer`  here a info: https://blog.stackblitz.com/posts/introducing-webcontainers/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even possible to run node through browser without NPM commands?

No, it is not. Starting server software requires access to the server machine. Without any server software already running on the machine, the browser can't contact it.

Imagine what cybercreeps could do to us all if browsers could start server software, and weep.

There is a workaround. You could write software with a custom protocol handler, that could start software running on the same machine where the browser runs.  https://medium.com/swlh/custom-protocol-handling-how-to-8ac41ff651eb  But installing custom protocol handlers isn't trivial.

Comment: Okay, that answers all.